# Сделать автоматически действие по нажатию кнопки "Показать еще"

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function(){
    var page = 1;
    var pages = $("#pages").val();

    $("#content").load("news_results.php");

    $("#loadmore").live("click", function(){
        var next = page+=1;

        $.get("news_results.php?page="+next, function(data){
            if(next==pages){
                $("#loadmore").remove();
            }

            $("#content").append(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Такой вот код кнопки которая показывает больше статей, например. Как сделать это действие автоматическим? чтобы при прокрутке к конце списка статей подгрузились остальные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var page = 1;
    var pages = $("#pages").val();
    var is_loaded = false;

    $("#content").load("news_results.php");

    $("#loadmore").live("click", function(){
        var next = page+=1;

        is_loaded = true; // Устанавливаем флаг
        $('.preloader').show();

        $.get("news_results.php?page="+next, function(data){
            if(next==pages){
                $("#loadmore").remove();
            }

            is_loaded = false;  // Снимаем флаг
            $('.preloader').hide();

            $("#content").append(data);
        });
    });

    $(window).scroll(function() {
         if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
              //Пользователь долистал до низа страницы
              if (is_loaded == false) { // Прогрузка прям сейчас не происходит
                    $("#loadmore").click(); // Имитация клика
              }
         }
    });

});
```

Comment: А можете еще подсказать как прелоадер прикрепить снизу?

Comment: Точно так же как и флаги - обновил свой ответ.

Comment: Переменную is_loaded неправильно задефайнили вначале))

Comment: угу, поправил..